# replacing contents of phone querySelector("[href='tel:123.123.1234']") but leaving in tel:

Tags: javascript, css

I have a form where a user fills out their phone number. this is part of an email signature generator. When you generate it, the placeholder a href phone number is replaced with the phone number that the user input on the form. This works fine except is also replaces "tel:" so the end result is for example '345.345.3456' when I want it to be 'tel:345.345.3456' so that it is clickable. I would like to replace everything EXCEPT the tel so that the phone number will be clickable.

EDIT: I have added the full code for the particular ask below now. I removed as much as I could of all those things not related to the question.

```html
<body>
<!-- Start main form -->
<form method='POST' action='.' enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' role="form" id="signatureForm">
  <p id='formErrorContainer'></p>
  <label for='mobile_phone'>Mobile Phone Number
    <input type='tel' id='mobile_phone' name='mobile_phone' title='Enter phone number' placeholder='e.g. 555.123.4567'>
    <span>Enter valid phone number</span> <span class='success-validation-check'></span> </label>
  <button type='submit' title='Generate Email Signature!!!' id='generateButton'>Generate Email Signature</button>
</form>
<template id="signatureTemplate">
  <table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
    <tbody>
      <tr height="25">
        <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">m: </span> <a href="tel:" style="color: #7D8D9A; text-decoration:none !important;"> <a href="tel:123.123.1234" style="text-decoration:none !important; color: #063852 "><span data-column="mobile_phone"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>

        // Adding the error validation
        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select');
        const inputLength = inputs.length;

        for (let i=0; i<inputLength; i++) {
            inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
                if (!this.classList.contains('blurred')) {
                    this.classList.add('blurred');
                }
            }, false);
        }

        const signatureForm = document.getElementById("signatureForm");
        signatureForm.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
            if (signatureForm.checkValidity()) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                const templateEle = document.getElementById("signatureTemplate").content.querySelector("table");
                templateEle.querySelector("[data-column='mobile_phone']").innerText = document.getElementById("mobile_phone").value;
                templateEle.querySelector("[href='tel:123.123.1234']").href = document.getElementById("mobile_phone").value;
                document.querySelector("body").innerHTML = "";
                document.querySelector("body").appendChild(templateEle);
            }

        }, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm still not entirely sure if it's what you're after but I think this will get you closer. I started to put in some extra flare for validation etc but I've got to run for the day and don't have the free time to go setup patterns and maxlengths and etc, so feel free to ignore the stuff you don't need.

**SECOND TRY**

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input, select'),
      signatureForm = document.getElementById("signatureForm"),
      template = document.getElementById("signatureTemplate"),
      phoneInput = document.getElementById('phone-input'),
      phoneOutput = signatureTemplate.content.getElementById('phone-output');
      
signatureForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => handleForm(e), false);

for (let i=0, x = inputs.length; i < x; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
        if (!this.classList.contains('blurred')) {
            this.classList.add('blurred');
        }
    }, false);
}

handleForm = (e) => {

  if (signatureForm.checkValidity()) {

     e.preventDefault();
     if (template) {
      const table = document.getElementById('signatureTemplate').content;
      phoneOutput.href = `tel:${phoneInput.value}`;
      phoneOutput.innerText = phoneInput.value ? phoneInput.value : 'NO NUMBER PROVIDED';
      document.body.appendChild(table);
     } else { console.error('No template found in the document') }

  } else {
    inputs.forEach((input) => input.classList.add(input.valid ? 'is-valid' : 'not-valid'));
  }

}
```

```css
.the-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.blurred {
  /* For the sake of example */
  outline: gray 1px dashed;
}

.anchor-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #063852;
}

.default-input {
  border: #ddd 2px solid;
}

.is-valid {
  border: #0f0 2px solid;
}

.not-valid {
  border: #f00 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<form id="signatureForm"
      method="POST"
      action="."
      enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      onsubmit="handleForm(event)">

  <p id="formErrorContainer"></p>
  <label for="mobile_phone">
    Mobile Phone Number
    <input type="tel"
           class="default-input"
           id="phone-input"
           min-length="10"
           title="Enter phone number"
           placeholder="e.g. 555.123.4567">
  </label>
  <aside data-phone-invalid>
    <span>Enter valid phone number</span> <span class='success-validation-check'></span>
  </aside>
  <button title="Generate Email Signature!!!"
          id="generateButton">
    Generate Email Signature
  </button>
  
</form>

<template id="signatureTemplate">
  <table class="the-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr height="25">
        <td>
          <span style="font-weight: 600;">m:</span>
          <a class="anchor-link" id="phone-output"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

**FIRST TRY**

If I understand your question correctly, this should get your sorted. Cheers.

```js
inputToHref = () => {
  const anchor = document.createElement('a'),
        anchorVal = document.getElementById('phone1').value;
  anchor.innerText = anchorVal ? anchorVal : 'Enter A  Phone Number First';
  anchor.href = `tel:${anchorVal}`;
  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" id="phone1" placeholder="tel: 123-456-7890"/>

<br><br>
<button onclick="inputToHref()">Click to Generate Anchor Tag</button>
```

Comment: Chris, Really appreciate the response and apologies for my poorly worded question. Yes I think you are right but I am having a difficult time implementing your suggestion. I have updated the above to now include my full code. Hoping you can have one more look.

Comment: @thedommer so you've got some syntax and markup errors in there. Are you just trying to make the number entered into the input appear in the anchor tag in the table cell as a clickable link of the number?

Comment: hey it's repurposing some code I found so not ideal and I am certainly over my head. But I am so close haha so I am trying. yes you are correct. I simply want the output phone number to be clickable. Howeer there is a bigger context I was hoping to repurpose the same idea for: This will be the same for website field and for linked social icons. I want the user to be able to input website addresses, social links and phone numbers and have all output as clickable. So the website would be clickable and the social icons would have links to their own local social pages.

Comment: I have all the code completed for the entire email signature generator. now one of the last pieces of the puzzle is getting things to be clickable to user defined links.

Comment: some of those errors are probably because I pulled the code from my main much larger document so don't worry too much about that I think.

Comment: @thedommer see updated answer, cheers!

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Really really appreciate this. Will dive into it today.